# Publish-subscribe over clients in Progress 4GL

Tags: client-server, publish, publish-subscribe, progress-4gl

Is is there some way to put a publish between clients in the network in Progress 4GL.

An (ugly) way would be to "publish" (write) to the db and let all clients poll the db - but of course I would like to avoid that.

I am using in Progress OpenEdge Release 10.0B02.

Answer (score 2):

No.  There is no way to use the built-in PUBLISH and SUBSCRIBE statements across a session boundary.

Its one of those things that people ask product management for from time to time but it never seems to make it onto the planned feature list.

Comment: To some degree you could hide the "ugliness" behind some generic utility functions that handle the PUB & SUB.  That would make it a bit easier to use various indirect methods like a db record, a sonic message, a socket call and so forth.  It would also make it easier to change your mind about which method is best in different situations.

Comment: That's what I have heard. Thank's for the advices too, I will think it over.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use a JMS like Apache ActiveMQ for your purposes.  The publisher would be known as a producer, and the subscriber would be known as a consumer.  ActiveMQ supports the STOMP protocol; there is an open source OpenEdge ABL [framework](https://github.com/abevoelker/OpenEdge-ABL-Stomp-Client) I wrote that will allow you to create a producer or consumer in pure ABL using STOMP frames.

Comment: Thank you. At a first glance it looks good, I can however see that the code will not run in 10.0B02 which is not object oriented.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame.  I'm stuck with 10.1C at work which lacks some features later versions have that I would really like, so I feel your pain.